# In Ansible, using azure_rm, is there a way to assign a host to multiple groups using a single key value and a separator?

Tags: ansible, azure

Using the following sample azure_rm inventory file, is it possible to use a single Azure VM tag to assign a host to multiple groups dynamically? For example, if the Azure tag is

```
type="vmtype1,vmtype2"
```

I would like the host in question to be listed under 2 groups: vmtype1, and vmtype2

```
plugin: azure_rm
keyed_groups:
  - key: tags.type | default('unknown')
```